# How to doublespace a table using setspace?

Tags: tables, line-spacing, setspace

I have used `setspace` with `\spacing{1.9}` to meet publisher specifications of "3 lines per inch or 12 lines per 10 cm", but it does not affect tables, although the publisher has requested that the spacing be applied to tables.

How can I apply this spacing to tables?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.9}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
  \hline
 & col1 & col2 & col3 \\ 
  \hline
  50 & 19 & 7 & 26 \\ 
  100 & 10 & 20 & 29 \\ 
  150 & 1 & 7 & 2 \\ 
  200 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `setspace` package restores the normal `\baselinestretch` inside floats (and footnotes); you can override this decision by redefining `\@xfloat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\Factor{1.9}

\makeatletter
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\ifhmode \@bsphack\@floatpenalty -\@Mii\else
   \@floatpenalty-\@Miii\fi\def\@captype{#1}\ifinner
      \@parmoderr\@floatpenalty\z@
    \else\@next\@currbox\@freelist{\@tempcnta\csname ftype@#1\endcsname
       \multiply\@tempcnta\@xxxii\advance\@tempcnta\sixt@@n
       \@tfor \@tempa :=#2\do
                        {\if\@tempa h\advance\@tempcnta \@ne\fi
                         \if\@tempa t\advance\@tempcnta \tw@\fi
                         \if\@tempa b\advance\@tempcnta 4\relax\fi
                         \if\@tempa p\advance\@tempcnta 8\relax\fi
         }\global\count\@currbox\@tempcnta}\@fltovf\fi
    \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup
    \def\baselinestretch{\Factor}\@normalsize
    \boxmaxdepth\z@
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{\Factor}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
  \hline
 & col1 & col2 & col3 \\ 
  \hline
  50 & 19 & 7 & 26 \\ 
  100 & 10 & 20 & 29 \\ 
  150 & 1 & 7 & 2 \\ 
  200 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A shorter (and safer) possibility is to use the `etoolbox` package and its `\AtBeginEnvironment` command to add `\doublespacing` to the `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\doublespacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.9}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
  \hline
 & col1 & col2 & col3 \\ 
  \hline
  50 & 19 & 7 & 26 \\ 
  100 & 10 & 20 & 29 \\ 
  150 & 1 & 7 & 2 \\ 
  200 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with sidewaystable from the "rotating" package. I get `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\color@endbox ->\egroup`. An example is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18092793/texse65624.tex) Any thoughts?

Comment: @David I suggest you to open a [follow-up](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/3954) question.

Comment: Thanks, the followup, with the linked example from my previous comment, is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66070/1783

Comment: @David I've updated my answer; this new approach (with `etoolbox`) prevents the issue with `sidewaystable`.