# How to doublespace a sidewaystable using setspace?

Tags: tables, line-spacing, rotating, setspace

As a follow-up to a previous question, [How to doublespace a table using setspace?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65624/1783), I found that the solution is not compatible with the sidewaystable environment defined in the `rotating` package.

I have modified the example in the answer from the previous question to demonstrate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\Factor{1.9}

\makeatletter
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\ifhmode \@bsphack\@floatpenalty -\@Mii\else
   \@floatpenalty-\@Miii\fi\def\@captype{#1}\ifinner
      \@parmoderr\@floatpenalty\z@
    \else\@next\@currbox\@freelist{\@tempcnta\csname ftype@#1\endcsname
       \multiply\@tempcnta\@xxxii\advance\@tempcnta\sixt@@n
       \@tfor \@tempa :=#2\do
                        {\if\@tempa h\advance\@tempcnta \@ne\fi
                         \if\@tempa t\advance\@tempcnta \tw@\fi
                         \if\@tempa b\advance\@tempcnta 4\relax\fi
                         \if\@tempa p\advance\@tempcnta 8\relax\fi
         }\global\count\@currbox\@tempcnta}\@fltovf\fi
    \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup
    \def\baselinestretch{\Factor}\@normalsize
    \boxmaxdepth\z@
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{\Factor}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
  \hline
 & col1 & col2 & col3 \\ 
  \hline
  50 & 19 & 7 & 26 \\ 
  100 & 10 & 20 & 29 \\ 
  150 & 1 & 7 & 2 \\ 
  200 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex` on this document returns the error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\color@endbox ->\egroup 

l.40 \end{sidewaystable}
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand. What do you want to be doublespaced? Why all that code? Simply put `\doublespacing` after `\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\doublespacing %%% <--- here
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
  \hline
 & col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  \hline
  50 & 19 & 7 & 26 \\
  100 & 10 & 20 & 29 \\
  150 & 1 & 7 & 2 \\
  200 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to control things from the preamble, you can use `etoolbox` package as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{etoolbox}   %%% <----here
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\doublespacing}    %%% <---- and here
%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
  \hline
 & col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  \hline
  50 & 19 & 7 & 26 \\
  100 & 10 & 20 & 29 \\
  150 & 1 & 7 & 2 \\
  200 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Before the `tabular` environment, we have issued  the command `\doublespacing`. This approach affects all `tabular` environments though.

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution. The main thing that I wanted was to be able to just make a simple re-definition in the preamble that would be only used at one time point, and wouldn't require re-compiling the Sweave source.

Comment: Thanks - FWIW, I gave +1, not sure why there is a downvote.

Comment: I would like to use the etoolbox package but want to be able to override the \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\doublespacing}  in a single table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answer that redefining should not be necessary especially redefining a core LaTeX feature like float handling seems very brave.

However you get the error because you have

```
   \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup
```

Which is how it was in LaTeX2.09 last millenium.  The LaTeX2e definition of `\@xfloat` ends

```
  \global \setbox\@currbox
    \color@vbox
      \normalcolor
      \vbox \bgroup
        \hsize\columnwidth
        \@parboxrestore
        \@floatboxreset
}
```

Which means, if you have the `color` package loaded, that your redefinition has the wrong number of groups, and is not color safe, so you get:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\color@endbox ->\egroup
```